# Extracting first and last names from txt file and using it to get username from AD and import it into csv

Tags: database, string, powershell, csv, active-directory

as a test and a way to get specific data from AD i am trying to get the data based on a txt file filled with names and last names of users. I worked out that using `ConvertFrom-String`cmdlet allows you to split names inside the txt file into two separate values, thus enabling you to use (in theory) `Get-ADUser` to find the user from AD and its attributes.

The code i was using so far is the following, with random changes here and there as i tried various options to make it work. I have been able to get the data i need by storing names under variables and then using the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet to pick them up from AD, i was even able to export that data into the CSV file. The issue is cant make it work when there is a text file filled with several entries.

```
Get-Content C:\temp\users.txt -encoding UTF8 |
ConvertFrom-String |
ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter {(givenName -Like '$($_.P1)') -and (sn -Like '$($_.P2)')} -Properties *} |
Select-object givenName, Surname, SamAccountName | Export-CSV C:\Temp\usersexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a sub-expression inside a non-expanding string.  Check out Powershell's [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7) help topic for more detailed information.  But, the short story is you need double quotes to expand something like `$($_)`.

Something like:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\users.txt -encoding UTF8 |
ConvertFrom-String |
ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter "( givenName -like '$($_.P1)' ) -and (sn -like '$($_.P2)' )" -Properties *} |
Select-object givenName, Surname, SamAccountName | Export-CSV C:\Temp\usersexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Notice that I quoted the entire filter.  Technically `Get-ADUser`'s `-Filter` parameter takes a string so this is acceptable and makes it a little easier to read.

Also note: you may need "*" to make this work correctly.  Technically -like will work on exact matches, but it's more typically used when searching with wildcards.  In your case using `'*$($_.P1)*'` might help get you past the issue.

If you are confident in the values especially considering you are also using the `-and` operator you might think about using `-eq`.  However I'd be concerned as there's always a chance of common name collisions. For example in the US there could easily be 2 John Smiths in AD...

I'd also point out it's more expedient to use Import-Csv for this.  When corrected your approach is working, but below is more readable and easier to write in the first place:

Example with `-eq`:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\users.txt -header "givenName","sn" -Delimiter " " |
ForEach-Object{
    $GivenName = $_.givenName
    $LastName  = $_.sn
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter "(givenName -eq '$GivenName') -and (sn -eq '$LastName')" -Properties * }
} | 
Select-Object givenName, Surname, SamAccountName | 
Export-CSV C:\Temp\usersexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Example with `-like` and Wildcards:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\users.txt -header "givenName","sn" -Delimiter " " |
ForEach-Object{
    $GivenName = $_.givenName
    $LastName  = $_.sn
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter "(givenName -like '*$GivenName*') -and (sn -like '*$LastName*')" -Properties * }
} | 
Select-Object givenName, Surname, SamAccountName | 
Export-CSV C:\Temp\usersexport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You also may want to avoid `-Properties *` and instead define a more exact set of properties to retrieve.  In bigger jobs that's going to make a performance difference.

Oh and, you usually don't need to specify the encoding for `Get-Content` it's very good at figuring that out on it's own.

In PowerShell Core the default value for the parameter is UTF8NoBOM. NoBOM just means there's no "Byte Order Mark" declaring the encoding and so it shouldn't have any issues with a UTF8 file.  In Windows PowerShell 5.1 you may need to specify as you have.

It looks like this is a learning exercise for you, let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanky ou for the help, however the code doesnt work for me. I tried both iterations and none of them seem to work. The first one returns a syntax error, claiming that there is an issue with `-Filter` part of the code. The second one seem to not recognize the search filter. None the less, to anwser one of the points raised - i used `-like` and `-encoding` for specific reasons. `-like` was used because the names arent full, some are missing either a second name or a second surname. `-Encoding` was used because in my country we use Č Š and Ž letters that arent encompassed by default.

Comment: Also - i have been thinking if using the `displayName` as a filter might be easier? Expecially since all the names in the file are also displayNames by default. The only issue is i dont know how the spaces between names and surnames are interpreted by `Get-ADUser`.

Comment: Edited answer.  1st example was missing single quotes, I fixed it.  Though you may still need to add wildcards, made a note of that.  2nd code sample might have been failing to return due to the `-eq` operator.  I provided a 3rd example using `-like` similar to the question..  All 3 tested good in my environment using the best assumption on the file format you described.  If `-Encoding` works go for it!  I made some clarifications, version specifics etc...  I don't do a lot of internationalization, but my experience it `Get-Content` is pretty good at figuring it out.

Comment: Amazing! Thx, that works! Thanks for the clarification on the use of quotes, i already took a look at it and will do so even more in the future, as i have found microsoft docs a very valuable source of information.